# Tableview scroll is not working?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, ios7

`Tableview scroll is not working in iOS 6 but it is working in iOS 7`.

please help me what is the problem,

Comment: Add your code here to find error..

Comment: It's just a vague question that cant be answered by anyone at this point. Please share some more information/code or describe the specific situation you are having this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the Verical bounce property Enabled.